# Search plan cache for all query plans using a given index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a query I can run to search the plan cache for all query plans using a given index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using `sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan` instead of `sys.dm_exec_query_plan`. Using `sys.dm_exec_query_plan` you will lose stored procedures with deferred compilation, long-running stored procedures (in case the SP has not finished but its statement which is using the given index has already done), and multi-statement UDF.

Additionally, you should add hints to avoid possible negative influence on your working environment.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
DECLARE @IndexName AS NVARCHAR(128) = N'[YourIndexName]';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
   (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')    
SELECT 
DB_NAME(x.dbid),
x.ObjectName,
stmt.value('(@StatementText)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS SQL_Text, 
obj.value('(@Database)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS DatabaseName, 
obj.value('(@Schema)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS SchemaName, 
obj.value('(@Table)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS TableName, 
obj.value('(@Index)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS IndexName, 
obj.value('(@IndexKind)[1]', 'varchar(128)') AS IndexKind, 
x.plan_handle, 
x.query_plan 
FROM (
    SELECT try_CONVERT(XML, qp.query_plan) AS query_plan, cp.plan_handle, OBJECT_NAME(qp.objectid, qp.dbid) AS ObjectName, qp.objectid, qp.dbid
    FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp 
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats s ON s.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle
        cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan (s.plan_handle, s.statement_start_offset, s.statement_end_offset) AS qp 
) x
CROSS APPLY query_plan.nodes('/ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/StmtSimple') AS batch(stmt) 
CROSS APPLY stmt.nodes('.//IndexScan/Object[@Index=sql:variable("@IndexName")]') AS idx(obj) 
OPTION(MAXDOP 1, RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: I think you might have meant `/ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/StmtSimple`

Comment: I don't remember what was an issue I was solving, but I removed `StmtSimple` deliberately.

Comment: Interesting, all the plans I've seen have each statement inside a `StmtSimple`. Please give us an example of one that doesn't have it

Comment: I'll try to remember

Comment: I have remembered! `StmtCond` will be for queries like `if exists( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SomeTable )`

Comment: Hum, maybe `//*[local-name() = "StmtSimple" or local-name()="StmtCond"]` is better then.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT
    dm_exec_query_plan.query_plan,
    usecounts AS execution_count,
    dm_exec_sql_text.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats
ON dm_exec_query_stats.plan_handle = dm_exec_cached_plans.plan_handle
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dm_exec_query_stats.plan_handle)
WHERE CAST(dm_exec_query_plan.query_plan AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%index_you_are_looking_for%'
```

- beware of indexes with similar names like this: named `CIX_Customer_CreateDate` and `IX_CustomerAddress` will return from a search for `LIKE '%IX_Customer%'`

Answer (score 2):

As well as a simple text search, **you can also use an XQuery filter, which may be faster or slower.**

```sql
DECLARE @idx sysname = N'[IX_YourIndexName]';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
SELECT
    qp.query_plan,
    qs.execution_count,
    st.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs ON qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
WHERE qp.query_plan.exist('//Object[@Index = sql:variable("@idx")]') = 1;
```

Or if you want *just* the query plans:

```sql
DECLARE @idx sysname = N'[IX_YourIndexName]';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
SELECT
    qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp
WHERE qp.query_plan.exist('//Object[@Index = sql:variable("@idx")]') = 1;
```

You can also add filters on `@Database` and `@Schema` if necessary.

If you are copying the index name out of system views, make sure to use `QUOTENAME` otherwise it won't match.